LG WEBOS Audiodescription tag missing kind value using Dash
On LG TV webos TVs (webos 4.5 and webos 22) Dash manifest has setup of returning Audiodescription as below :
<AdaptationSet
id="2"
group="1"
contentType="audio"
lang="en"
segmentAlignment="true"
audioSamplingRate="48000"
mimeType="audio/mp4"
codecs="mp4a.40.2"
startWithSAP="1">
<AudioChannelConfiguration
schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011"
value="2" />
<!-- Common Encryption -->
<ContentProtection
schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011"
value="cenc"
cenc:default_KID="B8EF9970-BFAB-4D69-90D8-CE01CA9576C2">
</ContentProtection>
<!-- Widevine -->
<ContentProtection
schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:EDEF8BA9-79D6-4ACE-A3C8-27DCD51D21ED">
<cenc:psshlwv6lwv6tNadXN0IgEq</cenc:pssh>
</ContentProtection>
<!-- PlayReady -->
<ContentProtection
schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:9A04F079-9840-4286-AB92-E65BE0885F95"
value="MSPR 2.0">
<cenc:pssh>AHkALUgA+AA==</mspr:pro>
</ContentProtection>
<!-- FairPlay -->
<ContentProtection
schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:94CE86FB-07FF-4F43-ADB8-93D2FA968CA2">
</ContentProtection>
<Label>English (AD)</Label>
<Accessibility
schemeIdUri="urn:tva:metadata:cs:AudioPurposeCS:2007"
value="1" />
<Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="description" />
<SegmentTemplate
timescale="48000"
initialization="52621843-$RepresentationID$.dash"
media="52621843-$RepresentationID$-$Time$.dash">
<SegmentTimeline>
<S t="384" d="96256" r="1" />
<S d="95232" />
<S d="96256" r="1" />
<S d="96255" />
<S d="95232" />
<S d="96256" r="2" />
<S d="95232" />

</SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
<Representation
id="audio_eng_desc=192000"
bandwidth="192000">
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet> 

Despite role being specified for AD track as below :
 <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="description" /> 

Audio description track returned by the browser on LG is below :
 {
    "id": "2",
    "kind": "",
    "label": "",
    "language": "en",
    "enabled": false
  } 

As kind and label are both empty,its impossible to know this is AD track considering position of AD track is not guaranteed. LG uses quite old browser version on their TV.
Chromium 87 on WEBOS 22 and Chromium 53 on WEBOS4.5 I don't have other version of TVs to test on.
App is playing video natively without any player library. Just HTML5 and would rely on browser on TV.
Any idea why 'kind' is not populated ?
Without way to identify Audio description track exists, can't enable Audio description for accessiblity purposes
